# How to add bundle target in podspec

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I would like to make a podspec for [this static library](https://github.com/thestk/stk/tree/master/iOS).

In the library's Xcode project, I have a `.a` target for the library, and a `.bundle` target for a [bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Bundle.html), containing assets needed by the library. This bundle is not a directory, it's just a bundle target with references to files.

Is there a way to include that `.bundle` in the podspec?

Comment: How did you include the entire bundle? I'm trying to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`vendored_libraries`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#vendored_libraries) and [`resource_bundles`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resource_bundles). All of these options are in the [podspec documentation](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html)

Comment: so, I tried to do the same but it didn't work, can you check it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004090/how-to-include-bundle-in-a-pod-with-vendored-framework

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is

`s.resources ='path/to/SomeBundle.bundle'`

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one bundle, use the array form.

```
s.resources =['path/to/SomeBundle.bundle', 'path/to/someBundle.bundle']
```