# how to include bundle in a pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I created a pod which include a `vendored_framework`that I included using this line in the `podspec`:

```
s.vendored_frameworks = 'Pod/Frameworks/TheFramework.framework'
```

So, that framework is a "fake" framework, that's why I need to include it this way. Now I need to include its resources bundle too, that's why I don't know how to do. I have tried this:

```
s.resource_bundles = {
    'TheFramework' => ['Pod/Assets/TheFramework/TheFrameworkResources.bundle']
  }
```

But when I run the project it seems that the `vendored_framework` doesn't find any resources. So there is a right way to include that bundle?

Important: this pod is build as a framework

Comment: What do you mean by "fake" framework?

Comment: A fake framework is a bundle target with a .framework extension and some post-build scripts to generate the fat library for the .framework.

A real framework modifies the Xcode installation and generates a true .framework target. Real frameworks also use post-build scripts to generate the fat library.
more info here https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework

Comment: @TimBodeit I answered the question above

Comment: does the path to the .bundle use a symlink?