# Cocoapods spec bundle from framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I have created a framework which created a file named contents.bundle at the root of the framework folder at compile time.

```
internal.framework
   - assets 
   - Headers
   - Modules
   - build.bundle <----
   - Pkginfo
```

I need to be able to load this file from another project which is linked with that framework. I'm using Cocoapods for the dependency management.

What would I need inside the framework's .podspec file in order to declare that the build.bundle file can be read as an NSBundle by the consuming project?

Comment: Just use `*.bundle` on `resource_bundles` i think? Still need to point to the exact folder, just not sure if it will read the extra files or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add bundle target in podspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891897/how-to-add-bundle-target-in-podspec)